# Can these alternating series games be undetermined?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, descriptive-set-theory, determinacy

To each pair $(S,\mathcal{X})$ where $S=(s_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers and $\mathcal{X}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, we can associate the **alternation game** $A_S(\mathcal{X})$ as follows:

- Players $1$ and $2$ jointly build an increasing sequence of natural numbers $$a_0<b_0<a_1<b_1<...,$$ subject to the rule that $$\sum_{i<a_0}s_i>\sum_{a_0\le i<b_0}s_i> ... >\sum_{b_k\le i< a_{k+1}}s_i>\sum_{a_{k+1}\le i<b_{k+1}}s_i>...$$
- Player $1$ wins iff the alternating series $$\left(\sum_{i<a_0}s_i\right)-\left(\sum_{a_0\le i<b_0}s_i\right)+ ... +\left(\sum_{b_k\le i< a_{k+1}}s_i\right)-\left(\sum_{a_{k+1}\le i<b_{k+1}}s_i\right)+...$$ converges to an element of $\mathcal{X}$.

An [old question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426794/a-game-of-harmonic-seriess) of mine asked about the behavior of these games when we specifically take $S$ to be the harmonic sequence $s_i={1\over i}$, but turned out to be difficult to attack. I'd like to get a better understanding of *why* this sort of question might be hard, and this seems like a good starting point:

> Is it consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that *some* $A_S(\mathcal{X})$ is undetermined?

A positive answer to this question would help explain potential wildness, but would also seem to require us to be able to "code into" the alternation games (a la the [Banach game](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281240/is-the-banach-game-quantifier-intractable-beckers-guess)), and at present I don't see how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we take $s_i = 2^{-i}$, we should even get that $\mathrm{ZFC}$ proves the existence of some $\mathcal{X}$ with undetermined $A_{(2^{-i})_{i \in \mathbb{N}}}(\mathcal{X})$. The key parts are that different plays yield different reals (as nothing in the tail can overcome a difference in a prefix), and that each strategy is compatible with continuumsly many plays (as a move here doesn't constrain the future at all).

We should thus be able to do the standard trick of well-ordering both players strategies with the least possible order type, and then building $\mathcal{X}$ in stages to foil any particular winning strategy.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm embarrassed I missed that - thanks!